# Pass an array of geometry to PostgresSQL function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, java

I am trying to pass an array of geometry to a PostGIS function using JDBC with JAVA:

```
            CallableStatement proc = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call somefunc(?) }");
            proc.registerOutParameter(1, 7);
            PGgeometry[] arr = new PGgeometry[2];
            arr[0] = a;
            arr[1] = b;
            proc.setArray(2, conn.createArrayOf("geometry", arr));
            proc.execute();
```

a,b are valid PGgeometry types.
I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
```

Is this even possible to do? I found no good answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue, not related to geometry type.
I was JDBC3 driver, replacing it to JDBC4 driver solved it!